# ASP.NET Send PDF File from Remote share to user to open

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

So my code is generating a PDF report and posting it to a remote file share server, all that works so i know i have proper read/write access to the share.

Now i am attempting to create an "Open PDF" button which will basically just serve that file from the remote share to the user so the can open the PDF and view it without having to go to the file share itself and dig through it.

I've tried a few things but no matter what i do i get errors.

Ive tried this code, which i used to serve the file when it was on my ASP.NET server and worked fine, but it wont work when i give it a remote file.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report_Submission_" +   SubmissionID + ".pdf");
String filePath = "\\\\Fileserver\\Directory1\\Directory2\\Directory3" +       "\\Report_Submission_" + SubmissionID + ".pdf";
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

Using that i get the following exception
0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

I also tried doing this

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
```

And i get the same exception.

Ive even just tried

```
Response.Redirect(filePath);
```

But that doesnt work either.

Is what im trying to do possible?  Can you serve a file from a remote file share without copying it to the local server first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Response.TransmitFile() with UNC share (ASP.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652792/response-transmitfile-with-unc-share-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","Binary"); 

Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.pdf\"");

Response.WriteFile(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"path\to\file\sample.pdf");

Response.End();
```